# Trying to start gazebo fortress through pybind, undefined symbol - destructor

Tags: python, ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since the python bindings for Fortress are quite limited at the moment, I'm trying to write my own for my use case, which is to start a gazebo server, step forward one time-step at a time, pass instructions to my robot and return the state. (For a reinforcement learning project)

When I try to import my module, I'm getting "undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition6gazebo2v66ServerD1Ev"
I think this due to an issue linking the library, so I'm looking for the library file but I can't find it.

I've installed Gazebo Fortress following the install with ros documentation https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/ros_installation. I'm on ubuntu 22.04.

Where are the library files installed? Do I need to install from source or using a dev version?

-- edit --

Ok so I think that symbol that it can't find is the destructor for Server. So I'm not sure it's a problem with getting the library files anymore. It looks like the destructor is defined fine in both Server.hh and in Server.cc when I got the source code. Anyone know why pybind can't find it?

-- further edit --
I'm still getting this error for other functions on Server and ServerConfig that are declared in the headers but not given an implementation there, so I'm back to thinking it can't find the libraries to link...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29099/trying-to-start-gazebo-fortress-through-pybind,-undefined-symbol---destructor/) by [Lestes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182673/lestes/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok Turns out I was just missing a configuration in my setup.py.

I had

```
from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

ext_modules = [Pybind11Extension(
  "gazebo_rl_sim",
  sorted(glob("src/*.cpp"))
)]

setup(
  name="gazebo-rl-sim",
  ...
  cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules,
  install_requires="pybind11"
)
```

And I needed in my ext_modules

```
ext_modules = [Pybind11Extension(
  "gazebo_rl_sim",
  sorted(glob("src/*.cpp")),
  libraries=["ignition-gazebo6"],
  library_dirs=["path/to/library_file"] # not sure if I needed this
)]
```

I'm surprised pybind's documentation doesn't mention that you need the libraries configuration to use extrernal libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Lestes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182673/lestes/) with karma: 3 on 2023-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0